# How create a keyboard shortcout to launch an .jar file with Oracle Java 7 Runtine?

Tags: shortcut-keys, java, console, oracle

I know how to create a keyboard shortcut to launch an application. (All Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Custom Shortcuts)

I know how to run .jar files from Nautilius. (Right click->Open with  Oracle Java 7 Runtine)

But what I don't know is what command I must put in the "Custom Shortcuts" Command text box to run the .jar file, or what is the same, how run from the console a .jar file using Oracle Java 7 Runtine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this before with a shell script.  I haven't tested it from a custom keyboard shortcut, but give it a shot once.  This is what worked for me, and allows me to fire-up cassandra-gui by clicking on a shell script icon.

```
java -jar ~/cassandra-gui-0.8.0-beta1/cassandra-gui.jar
```

Basically, you invoke Java with the -jar option and give it the path of the jar file.

```
java -jar [path]/[filename].jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command:

```
./home/[userName]/[fileName].jar
```

The command above run a jar file at the user folder.